# How to make route to "/" (slash) in Laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to make a navbar in which I can navigate to my welcome.blade.php page

header.blade.php:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="{{route('pages/welcome')}}">Main Page</a>
```

web.php route:

```
 Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('pages/welcome');
});
```

I get this error:

```
Route [pages/welcome] not defined.
```

anyone know what's the fix here?

Comment: Check Laravel's documentation about routing. You're missing some essential knowledge. There is no route named `pages/welcome`.

Comment: is your `welcome` blade inside a folder called `pages`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

route:

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('pages/welcome');
})->name('page.welcome');
```

link:

```html
<a class="navbar-brand" href="{{route('page.welcome')}}">Main Page</a>
```

if you want put address in the form of `pages/welcome` should set `url()` method instead of `route()` like below:

```html
<a class="navbar-brand" href="{{url('pages/welcome')}}">Main Page</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

here `route('pages/welcome')` this code expect a route defined in `web.php` has `name('pages/welcome')`

which will be

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('pages/welcome');
})->name('page/welcome');
```

likewise
if you `{{ route('test') }}` then `Route::get('/',....)->name('test');`

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#named-routes